# Measuring afferent and efferent coupling in a Ruby on Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, architecture, metrics

I am trying to study a medium size Ruby on Rails app (~300 models) for coupling patterns in the code architecture. From my research, the afferent and efferent coupling metrics are some of the most well known metrics to measure that. But, I have no idea how to go about generating those metrics.

Is there a free or paid tool that generates these metrics for a Ruby on Rails app? If not, how could one write some scripts oneself to do the measurement themselves?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is an off topic question for two reasons: we don't do software recommendations on Stackoverflow as it just attracts spam and opionated based answers (I used X and it worked great for me!). "If not, how could one write some scripts oneself to do the measurement themselves?" is not an actual practical programming question that can be answered in a few paragraphs. The scope and breadth here is huge. This is a Q&A site and not a forum and if you want to discuss how to implement an entire feature there are better places like http://reddit.com/r/rubyonrails

Comment: Actually stack overflow is a mix of WIKI&Forum Q&A site. I was looking for a tool to measure Afferrent and Efferent Stability/Instability metrics (Coupling Metrics) in Ruby code and the only thing I found was this, which is not an answer but rather a lecture... :(

Comment: Were you able to find a way to measure these metrics?